# Flask / Redshift : Avoid running same query in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, psycopg2

I have a flask app that links up to our database and runs a handful of queries to present the data. My issue is, I want to place a chart into the tab using the same data, but my only solution that has worked is placing it on another page, re-running the query and using a link to the img in the HTML. Locally, I had the SQL outside the routes, which did not work when I pushed it up to AWS.

Would simply like the page to run the query once and share the final return from the page1 query I pasted below. Thoughts?

```
@app.route('/page1')
def page1():
    some_sql
    return dataframe.to_html()

@app.route('/img')
def img():
    same_sql
    return image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI to anyone else looking for this, I actually found: Flask-Caching worked for my project here.. quite well, no major issues yet. [Flask-Caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the result of your SQL query. Usually, this is done with an in-memory datastore like Redis or Memcache.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.. that should work.. just wanted to make sure there was not a simple 'native' way to do this.